# how do i return all the paths after set point using bash

Tags: bash

i am returning this:

```
./nas/cdn/catalog/swatches
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/thumbs
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/cropped
./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings
```

what is the correct way to remove ./nas/cdn/catalog/ from this?

this is the code i have, so far

```
BASE='./nas/cdn/catalog'
echo $BASE
for d in $(find . -type d -regex "${BASE}/[^.]*")
do
    echo $(basename $d)

done
```

bit this just returns the last folder, i like to return /swatches, /product_shots/high_res etc...

Comment: `find "$BASE" -type d -printf '%P\n'`?

Comment: `-printf` is a GNU extension, but it's the best answer where available.

Comment: `... | sed -e 's;./nas/cdn/catalog/;;' | ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` like below,

```
BASE='./nas/cdn/catalog'
echo $BASE
for d in $(find . -type d -regex "${BASE}/[^.]*")
do
    sed 's~^\([^/]*/\)\{4\}~~' <<< "$d"
done
```

Example:

```
$ var="./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings"
$ sed 's~^\([^/]*/\)\{4\}~~' <<< "$var"
drawings
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler approach:

```
BASE='./nas/cdn/catalog'
echo "$BASE"
( cd "$BASE" ; find */ -type d )
```

Note: this is not perfectly robust; it will fail when any of the directories immediately inside in `$BASE` starts with a hyphen. It should only be used when you can guarantee that that is not the case.